# What does a double arrow mean on a schematic?

Tags: schematics

In this schematic, what might the double arrows at M5 and M4 represent?

This is in the power supply for a 1980's CRT monitor, if that narrows it down any.

[image: schematic]

Comment: I would suspect connectors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

Another example
[image]
Inline connector as seen in the image.

Ref. 1: http://nolanwebdev.com/6323/qM6f-6350/

I will add the source of images soon. Searching it again.

Comment: Nice! Where's that from?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, that's not a standardized symbol. So, this is specific to the engineer or the company he worked at, and there can't be a certain answer, but:

As these circuit diagrams often wander somewhere on the line between trying to show the idea of the circuitry and being helpful for servicing, and by the fact that these `<<` components have explicit designators (M5), they are almost certainly points where PCB trace connects to a wire bridge or an off-board component.

As @Tony points out below, it seems to be standard:

> It was a military standard for wire pin and socket in a connector that I used when I worked in Aerospace in late 70's

So, that kind-of-but-not-fully aligns with my suspicion.

Comment: It was a military standard for wire pin and socket in a connector that I used when I worked in Aerospace in late 70's

Comment: So, I'll add that info to the answer. Thank you, @TonyEErocketscientist!

Comment: I also have some background in mil-std/aerospace, and I immediately thought "connector", but not any specific kind.

Comment: The Anderson constant current loop (p 194, Robert B. Northrop: "Introduction to Instrumentation and Measurements", 3rd ed, https://i.imgur.com/vjkJTAj.png) also has these arrows, and it was developed by NASA...they just might be involved in aerospace ;)